# decision tree vs neural network for boolean function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, predictive-modeling, decision-trees

Which structure is more powerful in terms of expressiveness (i.e. it can represent a given Boolean function, accurately) — a single-layer perceptron or a 2-layer decision tree? (There are 10 features)

Comment: how many features do you have?

Answer (score 1):

A single-layer neural network has the potential to be far more expressive than a 2-layer decision tree.

The decision tree at most can use only two of the features. The neural network has the potential to use information from all of the features.

The decision tree can only use linear combination of the features. The neural network has the potential to use a non-linear combination of the features.